# No me agrega el segundo hash a un array

Tags: array, ruby

Estoy creando un array de *hashes* que son agregados en forma automática con un *input*, el problema es que cuando quiero agregar a un segundo usuario me borra los datos del primero.

```
people = {}
data = []

puts 'Write your name'
name = gets.chomp.capitalize
people[:name] = name
puts 'Write your age'
age = gets.chomp.to_i
people[:age] = age

print people

data << people
print data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### ¿Por qué borra los datos del primer usuario?

El problema se debe a que modificas las llaves del *hash* `people` después de volver a preguntar y, al agregarlo al *array* `data`, simplemente estás agregando una referencia más al mismo objeto *hash*.

Considera el siguiente código:

```
data   = []
people = {}

people.object_id
#=> 70339446093100

people[:name] = "Gerry"
people
#=> {:name=>"Gerry"}

people.object_id
#=> 70339446093100

data << people
#=> [{:name=>"Gerry"}]

data[0]
#=> {:name=>"Gerry"}

data[0].object_id
#=> 70339446093100
```

Como podrás ver, el *hash* `people` es siempre el mismo objeto (el *id* no cambia), incluyendo la referencia dentro del *array* `data`.

Continuemos con la secuencia de comandos, cambiando la llave `name` en el *hash* `people`:

```
people[:name] = "Alejandra"
people
#=> {:name=>"Alejandra"}

data
#=> [{:name=>"Alejandra"}]

data[0]
#=> {:name=>"Alejandra"}
```

Podemos ver que, al cambiar la llave `name` dentro del *hash* `people`, estás cambiando el nombre en todos los objetos que hacen referencia a ese *hash*, incluyendo el *array* `data`.

Sigamos la secuencia agregando nuevamente el *hash* `people` al *array* `data` (como lo haces en tu código):

```
data << people
#=> [{:name=>"Alejandra"}, {:name=>"Alejandra"}]

data[0].object_id
#=> 70339446093100

data[1].object_id
#=> 70339446093100
```

Nuevamente podrás notar que el objeto **sigue siendo el mismo**, por lo que el *array* tiene dos elementos que hacen referencia al mismo objeto y, como consecuencia, al modificar el *hash* `people` se ve el cambio en los dos.

Por último, puedes confirmar que sigue siendo una referencia al mismo código cambiando la información directamente en `data`:

```
data[0][:name] = "Diaz"

data
#=> [{:name=>"Diaz"}, {:name=>"Diaz"}]

people
#=> {:name=>"Diaz"}
```

El resultado es exactamente el mismo, modificaste el objeto original, así que tanto el valor de `data[1]` como `people` cambian.

#### ¿Cómo lo resuelvo?

Lo que tienes que hacer es generar un *hash* nuevo (en lugar de modificar las llaves de mismo *hash*) cada vez que preguntes y agregarlo al *array* `data`; por ejemplo:

```
data = []

puts 'Write your name'
name = gets.chomp.capitalize
puts 'Write your age'
age = gets.chomp.to_i

data << { name: name, age: age }
```

Como podrás ver, en lugar de utilizar una variable con el *hash* que quieres agregar al *array*, simplemente se crea un nuevo *hash* (i.e. `{ name: name, age: age }`) con la información previamente proporcionada por el usuario y se agrega como un elemento nuevo al *array*.

Puedes ver [aquí](https://repl.it/JT0T) un ejemplo de este código en acción.

O bien, si aún lo quieres, puedes utilizar una variable para guardar el *hash*, pero debes modificar la variable completa (no únicamente las llaves) para crear un objeto nuevo; por ejemplo:

```
data = []

puts 'Write your name'
name = gets.chomp.capitalize
puts 'Write your age'
age = gets.chomp.to_i
people = { name: name, age: age }

print people

data << people
print data
```

Puedes ver [aquí](https://repl.it/JT0W) un ejemplo de este código en acción.

Comment: aunque no agrego el hash en cada input, aun asi no me guarda la segunda opcion, este ejercicio es sin bd

Comment: @AlejandraDiaz ¿Podrías mostrar el código que estás utilizando? La solución propuesta no utiliza BD y funciona correctamente. Puedes ver un ejemplo en acción [aquí](https://repl.it/JT0T).

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, al final era el data que lo tenia adentro entonces me tomaba vacio el arreglo, lo saque del ciclo y comenzo  a agregar todo, muuuuuchas gracias por tu ayuda